# Wordpress wp_new_comment allow multiple comments

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working on a script which submit WordPress comments using `wp_new_comment` function.

when same user submit another comment it gives an error and not saving the comment,

i need to write comments always on comment_parent 0,

here is the code which call to `wp_new_comment`

```
$comment_id = wp_new_comment(
            array(
                'comment_post_ID'      => $course_id,
                'comment_author'       => 'LpAuther',
                'comment_author_email' => $user->user_email,
                'comment_author_url'   => '',
                'comment_content'      => $args['content'],
                'comment_parent'       => 0,
                'user_id'              => $user->ID,
                'comment_approved'     => 1,
                'comment_type'         => 'review'
            )
        );
```

Comment: Hi Suneth, So does this code work the first time a comment is created? What error are you getting? More information would help.

Comment: Yes it works first time, then shows a message "Found repeated comments; it seems you have already published it" I translate this message from Chinese, becoz i'm working on a chinese site

Answer (score 0):

I already got a solution add below code `functions.php`

```
add_filter('duplicate_comment_id', '__return_false');
```

Comment: So was the second comment a duplicate? If so, why would you want to allow duplicate comments?

Comment: it just use for a rating system by using custom comment type

Comment: I'm still confused as to why you would need to use: `add_filter('duplicate_comment_id', '__return_false');`

Comment: It doesn't matter, WordPress have that filter so we can use that

Comment: It kind of does matter as it's still unknown what actually caused the issue and why in the first place... I imagine that the `wp_new_comment()` function should return a different `comment_id` each time, so why was it duplicating the id?

Comment: it's not an issue, function default prams just preventing same user comments on same post at one level.it always return different comment id when we use above filter